# Get latest status out of 2 Tables Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want the newest status of the first table in my seconde table.
Table1:
ID/OrderID/Status
1/3/inactive

Table2:
ID/status
1/active

And output should be
ID/Status/newest_Status
1/active/inactive

The orderID is changing everytime a new entry is generated. So when ID 2 is changing to 'pending' the orderid is 4.

Actually I tried with lookupvalue function. But it dont give out the right  values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share few sample data.
your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the tables and manually edit same namens for same columns in M.
Group this tables by active/inactive and get the newest (maximum value).

Comment: Thanks medicat. I did it this way :)